# UIBarButton doesn't restore itself when I set customView to nil

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uiactivityindicatorview, custom-view

I've got a UIBarButtonItem that refreshes my data, and while the update is in process, I set refreshButton.customView to an instance of UIActivityIndicator, which is displayed fine. However, when data has been updated and I call refreshButton.customView = nil, the initial UIBarButtonItem is not displayed any more (just a blank space). Anyone knows how can I fix this?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You clear the custom view so it doesn't display anymore - that sounds correct.

Comment: No no, my initial UIBarButtonItem doesn't appear

Comment: Maybe you need to recreate the button after the refresh is complete.

Comment: Well it definitely solves my problem, but this solution is not as good as it should have been :)

Comment: I have the same issue, no pretty solution then?